# How to Iterator::chain a vector of iterators?

Tags: rust

for a given set of iterators a, b, c, one can chain them successfully with `a.chain(b).chain(c)`. Since the CLI util I am trying to write provides a vector of paths (strings, --dirs "a/b/c" "d/e/f" ...), I would like to use `walkd_dir` on each of them and then chain them together. My first thought is:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 0..3;
    let b = 3..6;
    let c = 6..9;
    let v = vec![b, c];
    v.iter().cloned().fold(a, |acc, e| acc.chain(e));
}
```

http://is.gd/hfNQd2, returns

```
<anon>:6:40: 6:52 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::ops::Range<_>`,
    found `core::iter::Chain<core::ops::Range<_>, core::ops::Range<_>>`
(expected struct `core::ops::Range`,
    found struct `core::iter::Chain`) [E0308]
<anon>:6     v.iter().cloned().fold(a, |acc, e| acc.chain(e));
```

Another attempt http://is.gd/ZKdxZM, although `a.chain(b).chain(c)` works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`flat_map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map):

```
fn main() {
    let a = 0..3;
    let b = 3..6;
    let c = 6..9;
    let v = vec![a, b, c];
    v.iter().flat_map(|it| it.clone());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, the type of a `Range` is different than the type of `Chain<Range, Range>`, and the type of the accumulator in the call the `fold` must always be consistent. Otherwise, what would the return type be from the `fold` if there were no items in the vector?

The simplest solution is to use a *trait object*, specifically `Box<Iterator>`:

```
type MyIter = Box<Iterator<Item=i32>>;

fn main() {
    let a = 0..3;
    let b = 3..6;
    let c = 6..9;
    let v = vec![b, c];
    let z = v.into_iter().fold(Box::new(a) as MyIter, |acc, e| {
        Box::new(acc.chain(Box::new(e) as MyIter)) as MyIter
    });

    for i in z {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

This adds a level of indirection but unifies the two concrete types (`Range`, `Chain`) as a single type.

<s>A potentially more efficient but longer-to-type version would be to create an `enum` that represented either a `Range` or a `Chain`, and then implement `Iterator` for that new type.</s>

Actually, I don't think the `enum` would work as it would require a recursive definition, which is not allowed.