# How to chain arbitrary number of iterables?

Tags: rust

I understand some of the jank involving iterables and arrays, but clearly not enough. I want to take any amount of iterables (vectors, arrays, slices, anything implementing `IntoIterator`) and provide an expected final size, and get an array (i.e. fixed-size) containing the chained values. To clarify, this is mostly for easy refactoring and function calling, so I want this utility to take ownership of the passed iterables and move all their contents into its output, such that:

```rust
let a1: u8 = [1, 2, 3];
let a2: u8 = [4, 5, 6];
let joined = join::<u8, 6>([a1, a2, ...]); // [u8; 6]
```

I tried implementing something with `chain`, but couldn't get it to work out. I know I can do this `unsafe`ly, but I'd rather avoid that if possible. Is there a way to do what I want?

My best (non-working) attempt:

```rust
fn join<T, C: IntoIterator<Item = T>, const N: usize>(iterables: Vec<C>) -> [T; N] {
  let mut a = vec![].iter().chain(vec![]);
  for iterable in iterables {
    a = a.chain(iterable.into_iter());
  }
  a.collect().try_into().unwrap()
}
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.Chain.html already does this?

Comment: also this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797777/how-to-iteratorchain-a-vector-of-iterators (e.g. you can use flatmap along with chaining)

Comment: I don't think that the person who closed this understood the question. `chain` cannot have static size. Your question has an answer, but it you would need to write seperate implementation for cases with different number of input arrays. Some numeric crates that deal with statically sized arrays (like matrixes) use procedural macros to generate implemenations for all cases.

Comment: @MaximGritsenko Since Rust now has cconst generics, it's not necessary to generate implementations for all desired target sizes anymore. There are two parts for this question. the first part is chaining all iterators, which can be done using `iterables.into_iter().flatten()`. The second part is collecting the result into an array – I'll add another duplicate for that part, though the OP already has a solution for this in the question.

Comment: Playground example combining the answers for the two different parts: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f7b9dc4655e9dad1d87053d66b14171f

Comment: @MaximGritsenko If you feel this should be reopened, please let me know.

Comment: I feel like this should be reopened. Both parts have been covered separately, but I've had trouble combining them into a convenient cohesive whole to be used for the intended purpose. I've since reached a solution similar to the one @SvenMarnach posted. Both these answers and the original question are not reflected in the so-called duplicates. My answer accepts a vector of slices and doesn't require the additional `C` generic parameter and an informative error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7c09babfa39c91f88c55f76c979dff8d

Comment: @EdenLandau Sounds reasonable to me, reopening.

Comment: And indeed, if you already have a vector of slices (rather than a vector of arbitrary iterables as in your original question), you can simply use `iterables.concat()`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad5125b500788c32867c986faa82fe48

Answer (score 1):

With credit to @SvenMarnach for simplifying, this problem is neatly solved like so:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn join<T: Clone, const N: usize>(iterables: Vec<&[T]>) -> [T; N] {
  let slice = iterables.concat();
  let length = slice.len();
  slice.try_into()
    .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("joined has length {}, expected {}", length, N))
}
```

Used like so:

```rust
fn main() {
  let params1 = [1, 2, 3];
  let params2 = [4, 5];
  print!("sum: {}", sum_six_numbers(join(vec![&params1, &params2])));
}

fn sum_six_numbers(ns: [u8; 5]) -> u8 {
  ns.iter().sum()
}
```